# What is the significance of C++ Core guideline F.15?

Tags: c++

[C++ Core Guideline F.15: Prefer simple and conventional ways of passing information](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f15-prefer-simple-and-conventional-ways-of-passing-information)

Here's the diagram of the advanced version of the guideline:

[image: Advanced parameter passing]

This raises the following questions (and possibly more):

1. How to distinguish when to use simple and when to use the advanced technique?
2. How to choose between `f(const X&)` and `f(X&&) & move` in "In & retain copy"?
3. Does "In & move from" denotes the case of r-value arguments to a function with rvalue parameters `f(X&&)`?
4. Shouldn't "cheap to copy" use pass by value every time (as it *might* enable return value optimization as well as copy-elision)?

Answers with an example would be helpful.

Comment: The leftmost cells, second and third from the bottom, say `f(X)` which I take to mean "pass by value" but this column says it's for things which are "impossible to copy."  How does this make sense?  I think I don't understand why "cheap to copy" and "impossible to copy" are in the same column.

Comment: (2) You're supposed to have both. (4) Can you give an example where `f(X)` would be more optimized? At the first glance, `f(X)` causes an extra move at worst, or is equivalent to `f(X &&)` if RVO happens. Also, I'm not sure why guidance for 'impossible to copy' for 'in & retain copy' and 'in & move from' is different, given they should mean the same thing here. (1), (3) - don't understand your questions.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `unique_ptr` is 'impossible to copy', but can be passed by value if you move it.

Comment: you should rather concentrate on one question per question. Did you read the following points? The table is just a crude summary of 6 guidelines and parts of your question are already answered there

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes, but unique_ptr is passed by value even in the "In" row, why not pass by const-ref if it's only an in-param (and not "retain copy")?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Now when I think about it, I agree that it makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnZwinck • I assume you mean `f(X const&)` to which I concur.  (Rather than `f(std::unique_ptr<X> const&)` which would be bad code smell.)

Comment: i would suggest you to edit the question and focus on a single question. Maybe from the answers already some of the other question will get clear and if not you can open followup question. The problem with many questions in one is that answers will have to be either extremely longwinded or incomplete. Also there might be duplicates for one question but not for the others. The thing about passing non-copyable by value for example would make an insteresting question on its own

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think the ownership of non-copyable types is assumed to be passed to `f()` in this table. If type is non-copyable, it implies some sort of ownership (since you can't just share this object around).

Comment: ...but better dont modify the question to ask something else once you got an answer ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818, I am confused about the whole guideline in general. I think of an answer explaining the rationale for each non-trivial cell in the table. Also, I couldn't find the answers in the following guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to distinguish when to use simple and when to use the advanced technique?

If you don't know of a reason to use something else, then simple is a good choice.

> 2. How to choose between f(const X&) and f(X&&) & move in "In & retain copy"?

Do you mean, how to choose which overload to call? If you want to keep the original then call with an lvalue, if you don't, then call with an rvalue.

> 3. Does "In & move from" denotes the case of r-value arguments to a function with rvalue parameters f(X&&)?

I believe `f(X&&)` denotes a function with rvalue reference parameter. Rvalue references can be bound only to rvalues.

> 4. Shouldn't "cheap to copy" use pass by value every time (as it might enable return value optimization as well as copy-elision)?

RVO cannot be used with an IN/OUT argument. And copy elision isn't important anyway when copying is cheap.

Regardless of RVO (or lack thereof), it is simply not possible to modify an argument without indirection, so IN/OUT argument is a reference. `X f(X)` is fine for cheap to copy types however. In this case the argument simply is an IN argument rather than IN/OUT argument.

"In & move from" doesn't really apply to the cheap portion in my opinion, but rather to the move only types that are crammed into the same column. All other rows besides this and IN/OUT suggest passing by value.

Comment: in Q4 I meant optimization with the following function: `X f(X)` instead of `f(X&)`. [F.16](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f16-for-in-parameters-pass-cheaply-copied-types-by-value-and-others-by-reference-to-const) says for cheap to copy objects pass them by copy. So returning a copy can be avoided by return value optimization in a few cases.

Comment: @madhur4127 Not in cases where you return the argument.